# AngularJs ng-repeat looping through 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to achieve this view by looping through 2 arrays [image]

but from the ng-repeats that I'm using, I get this view

[image]

This is the code that I have right now

```
$scope.properties = ["First name", "Last name"];

$scope.labels = ["john", "doe"];

//jade
.col-md-12
    .col-md-6(ng-repeat="property in properties")
        label {{ property }}
    .col-md-6(ng-repeat="label in labels")
            {{ label }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Use `$index` it will give the current index in properties array

HTML

```
 <div ng-repeat="prop in properties" class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>{{prop}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>{{labels[$index]}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JADE

```
.col-md-12(ng-repeat='prop in properties')
  .col-md-6
    label {{prop}}
  .col-md-6
    label {{labels[$index]}}
```